# Both Software Center and Synaptic Package manager won't download packages

Tags: installation, software-center, package-management

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on a Toshiba Satellite Laptop.

I am trying to download Labyrinth mind-mapping tool. However, neither the software center nor the synaptic package manager will download anything. I can download the tar.gz but I want to install from the repositories (I've had some issues with organization with tar.gz's in the past).

There is no error message when using either. Once I click "install" (or in the case of Synaptic Package Manager "Apply") the downloading screen appears and just sits at "0 bytes of 98.4Mb" forever. I tried with other programs and all are the same. Nothing downloads. After 10 or so minutes I can cancel the download just fine with no error messages. The computer works fine while trying to download. I tried running a bunch of other programs to see if I had any CPU speed loss or freezing and I didn't. The System Load indicator doesn't show a spike in CPU usage either.

This is also not a problem with my internet speed or network because I tried downloading large video files from online (using Google Chrome) and they downloaded just fine. Ubuntu One is backing up my files instantaneously, and both my Dropbox and my Insync are working like lightning. My PING is at 64, my downloading speed is about 34Mbps, and my upload speed is at 3.3Mbps. Here are the speedtest results:

http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3125146580

Again, it isn't giving any error messages so I don't know what else to say.

Any help correcting the problem would be awesome. I am sure there is a command I could put into the terminal to install the repository but what I would really like is to repair whatever is broken with both Software Center and Synaptic Package Manager.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: What is the name of the software?

Answer (score 0):

try to install that software Labyrinth or whatever the name using Terminal `sudo apt-get install ....` (name of software instead of dots) and see where you get, paste the code from Terminal here if it won't work, if you need clean up follow this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381774/ubuntu-13-10-64bit-issue-with-broken-dependencies/381776#381776) after clean up install it again, if you didn't succeed last time. You can also download it from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/labyrinth) if you really need it that much, there's even newer version available.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install labyrinth`
`E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`
`E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?'code'`

Comment: Never mind. I ran the task manager and found that for some reason synaptic pkg mngr was running in the background even though it was closed on the sidebar. But the terminal is stuck on the step where it is supposed to download it: `Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y` I pressed Y: 
`0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)]` And now it is sitting at 0% infinitely...

Comment: do you have any firewall software installed that can limit your access to some sources? take one more look at [this](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/l/labyrinth/install.html) if it also won't work please paste the code from the Terminal here, when it's stuck at 0%